# JavaFX Button visible if number<0

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I want to bind a `Button` visible property so the `Button` will  be visible when **ListNumber is <0**.The `ListNumber` is an `int`.

I have and one other which similarly i want to be visible if **ListNumber<500**;

I am searching in `Bindings` class for a good method but most methods require `ObservableNumberValue` interface.

I don't want to make `ListNumber` an `IntegerProperty`.

Comment: Making listNumber an IntegerProperty and then writing `button.visibleProperty().bind(listNumber.lessThan(0))` is the recommended way to achieve what you wish.  But you state that you in your question that you do not wish to do this.  I have no other recommendation.

Comment: @jewelsea doing this IntegerProperty i have other problems with the code.I have to modify a lot of classes.There is no other way really?

Comment: Potentially you could use a [javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanIntegerProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanIntegerProperty.html) with an appropriate [builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanIntegerPropertyBuilder.html), following all of the instructions and rules outlined in the documentation for that class, including `PropertyChangeListener` or `fireValueChangedEvent()` support.  I haven't tried it, but perhaps it is applicable for you.

Comment: Forgoing the use of Observables means you have to keep notice of changes to the value yourself. This means you have to check after every change to the variable, and change the visibility of the buttons accordingly - which is equivalent to using Observables, only you are writing the code. If the variable is publicly accessible it becomes even more of a hassle....

Comment: To me this sound like *"I want to swim, but I do not want to touch water!"*. There may be ways of achieving this but without a clear reason just seems to be a crazy idea to me. BTW: Having to change other classes when changing the type of a field is just a symptom of a design flaw: Allowing other classes to access non-final fields instead of making them private and allow access through getter/setter.

Comment: I changed it to IntegerProperty.Seems a lot of better way to go.Not designed the classes good from the beginning.Fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see any problems making `int` an `IntegerProperty`. What do you think encapsulation is for? You can implement it like this:

```
public class Model {

    private IntegerProperty listNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public int getListNumber() {
        return listNumber.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty listNumberProperty() {
        return listNumber;
    }

    public void setListNumber(int listNumber) {
        this.listNumber.set(listNumber);
    }
}
```

Than bind it to your buttons:

```
Button button = new Button("I'm a Button!");
button.visibleProperty().bind(Bindings.lessThan(0, model.listNumberProperty()));
```

And in all other places just use this property as an int:

```
int value = model.getListNumber();
```

Even if you are using listNumber as some static variable, nothing prevents you from wrapping it with a static getter. I think every IDE has replace/refactor functionality, so changing `ListNumber` to `getListNumber()` can be done in no time.